# Flexbox question: can you avoid a link to be treated as child of flex li?

Tags: css, flexbox, hyperlink, html-lists

I have a list on a website, populated by CMS. The :before of li items is a number (counter-increment) very high font size, and the text must be vertically aligned to this number. Everything is ok, except when the client adds a link inside the "li". Then it's treated as a flex element and displays accordingly...
I know one solution would be to have all the "li" content wrapped inside a "p", but that's not what the CMS outputs...

Here's a codepen showing the problem:
https://codepen.io/stebal/pen/RwVEByq

is there a way to tell the link not to be treated as a child of the flexed li ?

html:

```
<div class="list-wrapper">
<ol>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. <a href="#">My link</a></li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </li>
</ol>   
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.list-wrapper {
        max-width:300px;
}
ol {
    counter-reset: ol-counter;
    li {
        counter-increment: ol-counter;
        list-style-type: none;
        position:relative;
        min-height:84px;
        padding-left: 40px;
        display:flex;
        align-items:center;
        &::before {
            position: absolute;
            content: counter(ol-counter);           
            left: -10px;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size:84px;
            line-height:84px;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `a {
 display: contents;
}`

Comment: thanks, very cool :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks Fatima Mazhit
a {     display: contents; }